# Crypto error on decipher.update

Tags: node.js, encryption, middleware, node-crypto

I'm writing a javascript module for a Node project.

I get a very ambiguous error

```
protocol\Parser.js:82
     throw err;

TypeError: error:0000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
    at Decipher.Cipher.update (crypto.js:279:27)
```

Below is my javalogin.js file.
The error seems to be happening at the `decipher.update(rows[i].CC, 'hex', 'utf8');` line.

I do get some console print out.

```
      console.log('DB UserName:', rows[i].UserName); //returns correct username
      console.log('DB CC: ', rows[i].CC); //returns 2bf9kdk02kdnf3dk (correct CC hash on db)
```

JavaLogin.js:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var sha = require('sha1');


var algorithm = 'aes256'; // or any other algorithm supported by OpenSSL
var key = 'secret';
var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, key);
var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, key);
decipher.setAutoPadding(auto_padding=true);

var db = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      host     : 'host location',
      user     : 'username',
      password : 'password',
      database : 'databaseName',
    }
);

exports.auth = function(query, callback){

  db.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {

      if (err) throw err;

      for (var i in rows) {
          console.log('DB UserName:', rows[i].UserName);
          console.log('DB CC: ', rows[i].CC);

          var decrypted = decipher.update(rows[i].CC, 'hex', 'utf8');
          decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
          console.log(decrypted);

      }

      var info = rows;

      return callback(null,info);
  });
};

exports.add = function(query, callback){

  db.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {

    var encrypted = cipher.update('ccnumber', 'utf8', 'hex');
    encrypted += cipher.final('hex');

      if (err) throw err;

      // for (var i in rows) {
      //     console.log('DB Info:', rows[i].UserName);
      // }

      var info = rows;

      return callback(null,info);
  });
};
```

Comment: IIRC, using the builtin crypto, after you request the answer for your input, you need to build a new crypto object to start adding input to.  Also, what version of Node.js are you using? They've updated crypto to fix issues.

Comment: NodeVersion: v0.10.31

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that small but useful help in the comments. I figured it out because of that.

In the Original Post i was trying to set `var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,key);` to a global variable so i can use it in multiple functions in my JavaLogin.js.

If someone can show me how to do that, i would appreciate it.

Working Code section below:

```
exports.auth = function(query, callback){

  db.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {

      if (err) throw err;

      for (var i in rows) {
          console.log('DB UserName:', rows[i].UserName);
          console.log('DB CC: ', rows[i].CC);

var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, key); //moved this from the top of the file
          var decrypted = decipher.update(rows[i].CC, 'hex', 'utf8');
          decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
          console.log("decrypted:" + decrypted);

      }

      var info = rows;

      return callback(null,info);
  });
};
```